# Problems when adding to values in a list.[python 2.7.10]

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can't seem to add to the hour. I tried making a clock with a list. A fastforward clock.

Thanks for any help! The problem will be in the first 'if' statement.

```
import random
import time

ctime = [10, 00] #current_time
#s = random.uniform(.3,1)
s = float(.01)

while True:
      if ctime[1] == 59:
            time.sleep(s)
            ctime.remove(ctime[1])
            ctime.insert(00,1)
            nhour = int(ctime[0]+1) #next_hour
            ctime.insert(nhour, 0)
      elif ctime[0] == 23 and ctime[1] == 59:
            ctime.remove(ctime[0 and 1])
            ctime.insert(00)
            ctime.insert(00)
      else:
            ctime[1]+=1
            time.sleep(s)
      print(ctime)
```

## Update:

Forgot to show you the output, sorry. It continues as normal, the minutes going from 0-59 and then back to 0, however the hour changes to 02 and stays as 02 even after the minutes have gone by.

Comment: So what exactly is your issue ? Can you show what output you are vetting and what you expected ?

Comment: As a general comment, a `list` is an *extremely* poor choice of data structure for this use case.  A `dict` makes more sense, and a `class` is better still.  And python already includes several such classes https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: further, `ctime.remove(ctime[0 and 1])` likely doesn't do what you think it does.  `0 and 1` is just `0`, so this means that you have `ctime.remove(ctime[0])`, which just removes the first element.  Then you insert two new elements, which means that your `ctime` list will grow by one element for every "day" it ticks past.  You effectively have a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got your argument order for `list.insert()` confused.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

> list.insert(i, x) Insert an item at a given position. The first
>   argument is the index of the element before which to insert, so
>   a.insert(0, x) inserts at the front of the list, and a.insert(len(a),
>   x) is equivalent to a.append(x).

**edit:** Sorry, forgot to do the actual correction.

Try `ctime.insert(1,0)` instead.

And also `ctime.insert(0, nhour)`

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong kind of data structure.  Lists are for moving a bunch of similar items around so that each can be processed individually.  It's a collection.  That's not what you're doing.  You're trying to take a group of things, and treat them as a single unit, which has known interactions.

What you need is a class.  Python already contains [many date/time classes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html), but we can go ahead and implement your use case like this, just for illustration.

```
class Ticker(object):
    def __init__(self, hour, minute):
        self.hour = hour
        self.minute = minute

    def tick(self):
        self.minute = (self.minute + 1) % 60
        self.hour = (self.hour + 1) % 24 if self.minute == 0 else self.hour
```

And now your loop is much simpler

```
ticker = Ticker()
while True:
    print("%d:%d" % (ticker.hour, ticker.minute))
    time.sleep(s)
    ticker.tick()
```